# Is there an adjective describing what one *is* on one's birthday?

Tags: single-word-requests

There's this simple, efficient adjective in Dutch called `jarig`. It means something along the line of *having your birthday*. It's useful in many different sentences, such as:

> I feel so ***jarig*** vandaag.

I like this word a lot and it looks as if it's missing in English.

Is there any equivalent?

Comment: You could say 'in birthday mood'. or 'in holiday mood', or 'it feels like my birthday'.

Comment: In what sense would one mean your example sentence? Like happy as if it is their birthday?

Comment: I'm guessing that WS2 has guessed the meaning of the question correctly.

Comment: Reverting to comment. Re Bib's answer: _I feel so **birthday-boyish** today_

Comment: ..........older

Comment: ............old

Comment: Today I feel like it's my birthday. Today feels like Christmas. I feel special today.

Comment: To @EdwinAshworth's point, "older" is the correct answer to your question, technically.  I think you want to ask what one "feels" on their birthday. :-)

Comment: @KristinaLopez Except when one says *That's funny, I don't **feel** any older*.

Comment: That's true, @bib!

Comment: @bib _I don't feel any older._ That's funny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are talking about an adverb, the right way I think would be to just add "-ish".

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ish

Birthday --> birthdayish

I'm feeling birthdayish sounds reasonable to me.

The adjective sounds and reads a bit weird.

http://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/noun-and-adjective-forms

Birthday --> birthdayy

Comment: It sounded reasonable to me in my answer too. (Oh! I just saw that yours posted first!)  :-)

Answer (score 3):

Not and adjective, but it is common in the US to refer to celebrant children as **the birthday-boy** or **the bithday-girl**. These terms are occassionally also applied, somewhat jokingly, to adults.

Comment: @mplungjan Agreed. Occassionally the celebrant will wear a tee shirt proclaiming **BIRTHDAY BOY** attesting to his -ishness (just like the superhero wears a logo to proclaim his superness or batness).

Answer (score 1):

I often hear the word **special** used.  Might be as close as we have. I don't think there would be a direct translation to your word.

If you said, "Today is your special day."  It would infer that it was your birthday (unless you are getting married).

Like I said it isn't perfect but used a lot.

Comment: +1. I hear this alot. It might help if you provide one or more examples.

Comment: The only problem with "special" is that it doesn't refer to how one feels on their birthday, specifically.